# Print dates between range of dates

Tags: php

I want to know how to print all the dates between range of dates given in PHP 5.2
I do not want to call function for this task.

Comment: Is this supposed to be using an SQL query or PHP?

Comment: what you need is to print DAYS between range of dates given, isn't it?

Comment: well he stated "dates" between the range :)

Comment: Guys, need all the dates to be printed!! cheers!! :)

Comment: Need to print all the dates within the date range given

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
<?php
$start = '2013/01/01'; //start date
$end = '2013/01/30'; //end date

$dates = array();
$start = $current = strtotime($start);
$end = strtotime($end);

while ($current <= $end) {
    $dates[] = date('Y/m/d', $current);
    $current = strtotime('+1 days', $current);
}

//now $dates hold an array of all the dates within that date range
print_r($dates);
?>
```

Comment: Hi Ignas,thanks for ur valuable response... its giving o/p as Array[0]=> 1970-01-01 while i have slected some other date range